# TypeORM Timestamp Date equality not working

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM with an Entity that looks something like this:

```js
@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

However, when I try to do any sort of `timestamp` equality related SQL query using the TypeORM Entity's repository it does not work properly. For example the query:

```js
const id = 'dbe9e81d-aefa-459d-8460-707ade0fa156';
const userEntity = userRepository.findOne(id); // UserEntity(...)
const sameUserEntity = userRepository.findOne({ where: { createdAt: userEntity.createdAt } }); // undefined
```

Returns the correct entity for `userEntity` and undefined for `sameUserEntity`. I looked at the logs constructed by TypeORM for this query and it looks like this:

```sql
SELECT "UserEntity"."id" AS "UserEntity_id", 
    "UserEntity"."created_at" AS "UserEntity_created_at",
    "UserEntity"."updated_at" AS "UserEntity_updated_at" 
FROM "users" "UserEntity"
WHERE "UserEntity"."created_at" = $1 LIMIT 1 -- PARAMETERS: ["2022-02-19T22:10:13.564Z"]
```

It seems like TypeORM is not converting the JavaScript `Date` object to the correct PostgreSQL `timestamp` format. The timestamp in the database looks like `2022-02-19 22:10:13.564432`, which is a completely different format and is a higher precision.

Is there a specific way I should be doing `timestamp` related searches when using TypeORM?

Note: I've tried too look for people having this same issue but I do not see any clear solution. I'm trying to implement cursor based pagination around the created at date, however the greater than and less than operators are not work properly as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently ran into the same problem and fixed it by adding `precision: 3` to the column decorator. Please note that this is based on the assumption that you don't need that level of precision to begin with.

```
@Entity('users')
export class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ 
    type: 'timestamp', 
    precision: 3
  })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: 'timestamp', 
    precision: 3
  })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm seeing dates in logs like `2023-08-11T20:47:15.417Z` and dates in the DB like `2023-08-11 13:47:15.417294`

Comment: @KarimVarela Did you run a migration to remove the precision from the database? In my database, the dates are like `2022-01-13 14:49:25.258 +00:00`.